# webpack 3 DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack

I am getting this warning

> (node:4692) **DeprecationWarning**: `Chunk.modules` is deprecated. Use `Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule` instead

after upgrade from `webpack v2.6.1` to `v3`. In `v2xx`, works fine but the `v3` gives me this error.

I don't know which package causing the issue. Any references or link might be helpful.

[image]

[image]

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --colors  --port 2000"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "~2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.2.4",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.2.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~1.4.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/typeahead": "~0.11.29",
    "angular2-router-loader": "~0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "~0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.3",
    "chunk-manifest-webpack2-plugin": "~1.0.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "~0.4.0",
    "css-loader": "~0.14.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "file-loader": "~0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "~0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "null-loader": "~0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "split-by-name-webpack-plugin": "~0.0.3",
    "style-loader": "~0.18.2",
    "tslint": "~5.4.3",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4",
    "uglify-js": "^3.0.19",
    "uglify-loader": "~2.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "webpack": "~3.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~2.8.2",
    "webpack-chunk-hash": "~0.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.5.0",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0",
    "webpack-uglify-parallel": "~0.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting the deprecated warning in the `extract-text-webpack-plugin 3.0.0-beta.3`. After I update the extract-text-webpack-plugin to v3.0.2 followed by this link [DeprecationWarning  Chunk.modules in Webpack 3.x](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/529), the warning is gone and Webpack v3xx is working without any error for me.

**webpack**

`v3.8.1`

**extract-text-webpack-plugin**

`v3.0.2`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please explain what was the problem with that plugin and what solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, see related issue here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/529

Answer (score 2):

Swapping from "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5",

to

"webpack-chunk-hash": "0.5.0"

Fixed the warning for me. The new package is a fork of the old one.